# Generate openApi DTO's with NestJS without a Controller

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi

I am writing a NestJS service that provides a REST API and it publishes some messages to NATS.  We are using the NestJS support to generate OpenAPI docs, and from the OpenAPI docs we generate an SDK that we import into our clients.  This all works great, but only the REST API of our code is in the SDK.

What we'd like to also do is to have NestJS include the DTO's for the content for the messages we publish to NATS.  Then our SDK will also include interfaces for these DTO's, and then our clients can cast the message content to the correct interface (based on the message subject).  This way, the publisher of an event defines the content of the event, and users of it don't have to replicate the interface, yet they get strongly-typed code.

I've tried adding the @Api decorators to the DTO, but it appears that unless the DTO is used in the definition of an @Controller, it is not included in the resultant openApi docs.

I was hoping for a way to decorate a "random" DTO in my code so it will then be included in the swagger docs, and in-turn included in a generated SDK.  Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass extraModels array as a part of SwaggerDocumentOptions

```
SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config, {
   extraModels: [.......]
});
```

https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/241